# How to make things align in a footer

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I can't get my social media buttons to align left or right on the footer of my website. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, can anyone please help?

I have tried `margin-left`, `margin-right`, `float: left`, `float: right`

This is what I have and all it does is center.

**HTML**

```
<footer class="container-fluid text-center">
  <div class="row" id="contact">
    <p class="col-sm-4"></p>
    <h1>Reach me here</h1>
    <br>
    <br>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/Aarons_coding" target="_blank">
      <img src="images/twitter.png" alt="twitter" id="twitt">
      <br/> Follower me
    </a>
    <a href='https://www.facebook.com/freelancecoding/posts/1534409766779543' target="_blank">
      <img src="images/fb.png" alt="fb" id="fb">
      <br/>Like Me on FB
    </a>
    <a href='https://www.linkedin.com/in/aaron-s-706193125' target="_blank">
      <img src="images/link.png" alt="linkedin" id="link">
      <br/>Connect with me
    </a>

  </div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#top">Top</a></li>
    <li><a href="#design">About the Designer</a></li>
  </ul>
  <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d401398.0917589909!2d-85.9569564028764!3d38.18847214627973!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x88690b1ab35bd511%3A0xd4d3b4282071fd32!2sLouisville%2C+KY!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1470171263135"
  width="350" height="250" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <div style="clear: both"></div>
</footer>
```

**CSS**

```
#twitt {
  width: 95px;
  height: 95px;
  margin: 5px 5px 0 18px;
}

#fb {
  width: 95px;
  height: 95px;
  margin: 5px 0 5px;
}

#link {
  width: 95px;
  height: 95px;
  margin: 5px 5px 0 5px;
}

footer {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

footer .col-sm-4 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

footer ul {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  list-style: none;
}

footer li img {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
```

Comment: Hiya, someone seems to have already answered your question, but just to let you know if you weren't already aware, you can use [fontawesome](https://fontawesome.io/icons/) which ships with bootstrap or the bootstrap glyphicons classes to insert social media icons. They insert it as text, so it makes it much easier to style (you can do things like `text-align` or `font-size` on them.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably didn't set styles on correct elements.

If you do it like this it works:

```
#contact a{
  float: left;
}
```

Example here https://jsfiddle.net/hw3odrba/

Comment: Thank You! for you're help:)

Comment: I am glad that I helped. If it solved your problem consider accepting my answer by clicking green check mark.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a new style in your css, in case you want to align items to the right:

```
#contact a{
  float: right;
}
```